# Spnego Kerberos Spring SSO

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, kerberos, spnego, spring-security-kerberos

I am trying to implement SPNEGO Kerberos based SSO.
Below is the link from which I tried to implement it.
Form based SSO is working fine.
But when I try to implement using SPNEGO I get the below error

Try to validate Kerberos Token 
Negotiate Header was invalid: Negotiate

**YHwGBisGAQUFAqByMHCgMDAuBgorBgEEAYI3AgIKBgkqhkiC9xIBAgIGCSqGSIb3EgECAgYKKwYBBAGCNwICHqI8BDpOVExNU1NQAAEAAACXsgjiBgAGADQAAAAMAAwAKAAAAAYBsR0AAAAPREVNT01BQ0hJTkUxQ09FTEFC**

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Kerberos validation not successfull
at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.validateTicket(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.java:85)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:155)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.validateTicket(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:67)
... 28 more
Caused by: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSHeader.<init>(GSSHeader.java:97)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:306)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285)
at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.GSS_acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:871)
at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:544)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:342)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285)
at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:163)
at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:1)
... 31 more
```

Comment: Your server with your app and client browser on the same machine?

Comment: I need to know a bit more about your setup to help you out. Are the server and client on different machines? That's key as kerberos is not going to work if it is not. If you're trying to set up keytabs inside of Spring Security you need to use RC4-HMAC with some of the older Windows Servers as that's the best they supported. Can you please post more details how you have things set up (keytabs, machines, etc)?

Comment: The specific error that you are getting is a problem with the mechanism. For a detailed description of the specific fields you can look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995330.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kerberos error: GSSHeader did not find the right tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942234/kerberos-error-gssheader-did-not-find-the-right-tag)