# Kerberos error: GSSHeader did not find the right tag

Tags: java, soap, kerberos, spring-security-kerberos, jgss

I’m trying to make Kerberos authentication connection to a SOAP service wsdl url.
I’m able to establish connection successfully and make service calls.
After I start my server, I’m able to make successful service call at least once. 
However after few requests (1 or more ), I suddenly get invalid token error.
Once I get the error, future calls do not work and error persists.

IF I restart my server, then again service call works at least once. And above cycle continues.

**I’m unable to figure out why suddenly token gets invalid, though it worked earlier. *And restarting server makes token valid again*.**

Here is error stacktrace:

```
Caused by: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSHeader.<init>(GSSHeader.java:97)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:237)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find root cause for why token is invalid. But here is how i get around this issue.

My authentication was working for first time after I restart my server and bean is loaded again in context. So I changed scope of my spring bean to `prototype` so that every time new proxy bean is created.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the Base 64 value or a hex dump, I assume that the client is sending a NTLM type 1 token and Java does not support NTLM.